# Unhandled Exception Error C Programming

Tags: c, visual-studio, exception, structure

I'm a novice programmer, with probably about 8-9 weeks experience of C programming.
Currently I am working on creating a program that will read some lines from a text file, store them in a structure, calculating a couple things, then print the data out. I am using Microsoft Visual 2010 Express

Whenever I try to run the program, it immediately gives me an error message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x777915de in Lab 7 Part B.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x00460310.

My question - is there anything I can do to track down where this problem is originating?

I'm not 100% sure if I am allowed to post my entire code onto here, as that may be considered being a slacker and not figuring things out myself. Since I also have no idea where it's coming from, I can't post a specific block of my code either. Sorry.

If I try to run it once more it comes up to this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x777915de in Lab 7 Part B.exe: 0xC0000005: The
>   operation completed successfully.

Then it just stays there whenever I try to run the program several more times. Both errors ask for me to either 'Break' or 'Continue'.

If its any help, the second error consistently stops at this line of code.

> ```
> SetLastError(TL_LastError);
>
> return(ptd);
> ```

With the green arrow pointing at the return. The file the accompanies the error is called 'tidtable.c'. If I am able to uncover anything to help solve this, I will update this ASAP.

Thanks.

EDIT:
So I found out about F10 and eventually just worked through the code, and somehow found that the error is coming up when the yellow arrow points at the `getdata` line. Then when I press F10 once more, the error begins and stays there. I posted the blocks of code that I think are the culprits and hopefully will solve the problem.

Here is my main function:

```
void main()
{
    SCARADATA data;

    getdata(&data);
}
```

Here is the function:

```
void getdata (SCARADATA *data)
{
    int i;

    FILE *file;
    char fName [MAX];

    sprintf (fName, "(exactfilepath)");

    file = fopen(fName, "r");
    if(file==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid File.");
        system ("pause");
    }
    else
    {
        for (i=0; i<=10; i++)
        {
            fscanf (file, "%s\t%lf\t%lf\t%d", data[i]->stringname, data[i]->x, data[i]->y, data[i]->elbow);  
        }
    }
    fclose (file);
}
```

Here is the structure I am using to store the data read:

```
typedef struct
{
    char stringname[40];
    double x, y;
    int elbow;
    double ang1, ang2;
    bool isValid;
} SCARADATA [20];
```

And a sample of what the program is reading of the text file. There are 10 lines of this. (pt1 - pt10)

> pt1   -400    400 1

EDIT 2:
With fizzer's help, we have fixed the program. From his explanation, I was sending the address of the array of 20 structures into my `getdata` function, which is the same as the address for the first structure of the 20. What I did to fix the problem was added a `for loop` around the call of the functions to cycle through the address of each structure.

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
{
getdata(&data[i]);
findangles (&data[i]);
printdata (&data[i]);
}
```

This allows the program to pass the address of EACH structure into the following functions, instead of passing the entire array's address. The unhandled exception error, from what I gathered through is caused by the program not being able to store the information within the file into the array. This caused the compiler to then read garbage, resulting in an error each time the file is opened to gather data. At least, I think that's what happened.

Thanks for your help fizzer! Definitely saved me a couple nights staring at this code.

Comment: How long is your code? Could you post your startup code perhaps?

Comment: I guess somewhere it is related to heap corruption or some variable is reading a location which it should not supposed to be. Try to put breakpoints and debbug accordingly atleast you'll get a rough idea where it causing run time exception!

Comment: `main` returns `int`, not `void`. That's not the cause of your problem, but it's a sign that you may have learned it from someone who doesn't understand C very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&data[i]->x, &data[i]->y, &data[i]->elbow`

`scanf` needs pointers.  (data[i]->stringname is already a pointer to the first element).

*Edit*

What is SCARADATA supposed to be?  The type of the whole array of 20 structs, or the type of one element in the array?  I suspect the latter.  Here's one way to make your program run:

```
typedef struct
{
    ...
} SCARADATA;  /* not [20] */

/* . instead of -> */
fscanf (file, "%s\t%lf\t%lf\t%d", data[i].stringname, &data[i].x, &data[i].y, &data[i].elbow);  

int main() /* main returns int */
{
    SCARADATA data[20];
    getdata(data);
    return 0;
}
```

See the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) for details of arrays versus pointers.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. When I pass the structure into the function using '&data' doesn't that already pass the entire address into the function? Meaning, I only really need a pointer '*' to the addresses rather than an '&'?

EDIT:
Just tried your suggestion and it made no difference.

Comment: What you actually passed was a pointer to an array of 20 structs, probably not what you wanted.  See 6.13 of linked FAQ for what this means.

Comment: Having it the way you wrote the code would mean that I am passing a copy of the structure into the function, right? However, I want to actually change the array of original structures with the values gathered from the file.

Comment: No. In most situations, an array is converted to a pointer to its first element. See 6.3 of the FAQ. This is the same reason we don't need to put an `&` before `data[i].stringname` in the call to `fscanf`, but we need it for the other elements.

Comment: `getdata(data)` is equivalent to `getdata(&data[0])` and `fscanf(..., data[i].stringname, ...)` is equivalent to `fscanf(..., &(data[i].stringname[0]),...)`.  It's just what C does with arrays.  You'll get used to it.

Comment: Oh boy, so much information to take in. I think I'm more confused than ever., mostly because I was told differently. I have two other functions that use the call with &data and work perfectly fine using ->. However, it is only when I added the getdata function that everything went bonkers. If I may, can I post my entire code for a looksy?

Comment: When you pass `&data`, you pass a pointer to the entire array, which is numerically at the same address as the first element, so things might seem to work, kind of, for data[0].  Unfortunately, incrementing this pointer steps over all 20 elements, so accesses to data[1] and later are undefined.  Try `printf("%u\n", (unsigned)sizeof(*data));` inside `getdata()` to see the difference in the two cases.  If you're confused by the conversion of the array to its first element, just write `getdata(&data[0])` in full.  No confusion here, right?  It's just passing the address of the first struct.

Answer (score -1):

First, please note that C has no exceptions in the sense of C++, Java etc.

This "access violation" seems to be what in some other operating systems is referred to as a "segmentation fault" : you are accessing memory that you should not, because of improper use of pointers (or arrays, which are the same in C).

Advice : run this program in a debugger.

Comment: Exception is a perfectly valid term here and unrelated to C++/Java usage

Comment: He's using MSVC; MSVC has Structured Exception Handling (SEH).  It isn't Standard C, but it is Microsoft C.

Comment: Hmm, no.  Windows uses SEH to kill a C program that invokes undefined behavior.  Nothing to do with MSVC and entirely standard C compliant.